# Concatenating an optional and a string

Tags: ios, swift

I have a url variable declared like this

```
var url:String!
url = 'hello'
```

then I have the base url declared like this:

```
var baseUrl:String
baseUrl = http://google.com/
```

Trying to concatenate the 2 values together like

```
if let tmpurl = url {
    println(baseUrl + tmpurl);
 }
```

prints out

```
http://google.com/Optional('hello')
```

Why is there the Optional part in the output? I thought the `let` part would unwrap the optional

Comment: The typos in your question (wrong quotes/no quotes) leads me to believe that this isn't your exact code.  Entering your code in a playground (while correcting the quotes) results in `http://google.com/hello` for me

Comment: You don't need to unwrap `url` anyway as it is an implicity unwrapped optional

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing is that you are using an older version of swift. Please update to 2.1. Secondly this is because you have unwrapped the url variable but its not required. So update your code as:

## For swift 2.0

```
var url:String?
url = 'hello'

var baseUrl:String?
baseUrl = http://google.com/

if let tmpurl = url {
   print(baseUrl! + tmpurl);
}
```